# Write a name in a diagonal line representation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that will show a name in a diagonal line. 
I know I should add a variable with space, like \t, and increment it in each loop. 
I have tried to do this with no success. Any suggestions?

```
int main()
{
    string space = "\t";
    string firstName;
    cout << "Enter your first name:";
    cin >> firstName;
    for (int posChar = 0;
    posChar < firstName.length( );
    posChar++)
    cout << space << firstName.at(posChar) << endl;
    space=space + "\t"; // this is what I've tried, it's a long shot. 

    return 0;
}

output:
Enter your first name:Alexander
A
l
e
x
a
n
d
e
r
```

Comment: Braces like others said alread. And the indentation. It helps prevent quite a few errors if you make different scopes as visible as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would indent you code properly, you would see that `space=space + "\t";` is not part of the `for`.

Also, you should use a space instead of a tab.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string space;
    string firstName;

    cout << "Enter your first name:";
    cin >> firstName;

    for (int posChar = 0; posChar < firstName.length( ); posChar++)
    {
      cout << space << firstName.at(posChar) << endl;
      space = space + " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could submit some of your code (not necessarily this one) to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You have some bad practices when it comes to formatting and (lack of) indenting.

Answer (score 0):

Need { } on your for loop. Without it you are not adding the tab for each character but instead add it when the loop is complete.

If you do a for loop without a block then only the command following the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the opening and closing brackets for the code block?
The loop you wrote only does

```
cout << space << firstName.at(posChar) << endl;
```

and after it has finished it does once

```
space=space + "\t"; // this is what I've tried, it's a long shot.
```

It should look like this:

```
for (int posChar = 0;
posChar < firstName.length( );
posChar++)
{
cout << space << firstName.at(posChar) << endl;
space=space + "\t"; // this is what I've tried, it's a long shot.
}
```